# phpMyAdmin showing db and table names in URL

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there a way to configure phpMyAdmin to not show (and transfer back and forth to the server) sensitive items like Database name and table names in the URL?

In my app I do everything to obscure this info but need something like phpMyAdmin for back-end access.

thanks!

Comment: I might be off the mark here, but for what you're looking for, would it make sense to have phpMyAdmin access use HTTPS for security? Your question seems very valid, but I'm trying to think about who in particular might have a chance to see those URLs.

Comment: I have an https/tsl connection. Look at the querystring of the URL for PMA, it has it right in there. example string: https://mySite.com/pma/index.php#PMAURL-4:index.php?db=myDb&table=myTable&server=1&target=&token=******************

Comment: This is true, but who would have the potential to see the query string? I used to think otherwise and did some research, but from what I understand, SSL connections will not send the query string in unencrypted text; the most that might be cleartext would be "mySite.com"